# How do I identify that the next commit is going to be a merge commit?

Tags: git, githooks

I am writing a commit-msg hook which checks the message format.
But there are some rules I can not enforce when the commit is going to be a merge commit.
Particularly the length of lines in the message. I am enforcing the length of the first line to be less than 70 characters but this does not make sense when the commit message is prepared by merge and is often much longer because of branch names.

I think this could be accomplished by greping the first line of the message for "merge" string, but this does not seems correct to me. For example on windows, there is a "MERGING" string displayed in git bash prompt when merging is in progress. Is there any git variable or something like that what signals that I am going to merge?

### SOLUTION

As pointed out in comments, a `.git/MERGE_MGS` file is created during a merge and contains the prepared merge message. But there is also an empty `.git/MERGE_MODE` file created just to signal that merging is in progress. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi zandar, I don't think you can know if one of your commits will cause a merging conflict in the future. As far as I can remember, the commits happen in a local repository and afterwards you pull origin into your local repo or push your repo to origin and during those actions a merge-conflict can occur... no?

Comment: Yes, you are right, you can not tell anything about the possibility of a future conflict during a merge. And yes, in git almost everything happens locally as long as you want it localy. But identifying the state of merging from within a hook is another story... Still, thank you for your comment ;)

Comment: it doesn't look to me like merge invokes `commit-msg` at all: `echo echo hi >.git/hooks/commit-msg; chmod +x !#:3`, do a merge, it doesn't run, do a commit, it does.

Comment: Yes I know, this is quite tricky. When the merge goes without conflict, my `commit-msg` hook is not invoked an so I am out of the party. But when there is a conflict, you have to solve it and then create a commit which fires up your editor or you use git gui, than you edit the prepared message and after that, the `commit-msg` hook **is** executed. Now the `.git/MERGE_MODE` file comes handy.

Comment: Why try to get so hardnosed anyway? You have to vet everything in your production-ish repos' `post-receive`s regardless.  Supply the message-checking code as a filter, so people can `%!checkmsg` or whatever.  What goes on in their repos is their business, there's no more reason to examine or control that than the notes on their desks.

Comment: You figured out the main problem here. I have a `pre-receive` hook installed in my remote production repository which enforces some rules. But because almost everyone in my development team is LAMA regarding git usage and generally distributed version control system usage I am preparing the hook for these people to prevent them doing basic mistakes and teach them good commiting practice before they actually commit their changes locally. If I would simply reject their commits using my server hook, they would not be able to fix their commits and gets angry on me...

Comment: Have a local test-pushes-repository template that has your post-receive code in it so that they can easily clone and test pushing to it, to see if their commits are formatted right, or equivalently show them how to do lightweight clones for experimental work and treat their main clone as a proxy for the "real" one.  The ability to conduct casual exploratory work is a huge part of the value of git, and commit-message format requirements you need for your production repositories aren't at all appropriate for that.

Comment: I figured out the same solution as you did: to check the `.git/MERGE_MODE` file. But it doesn't work if user is amending an existing merge commit, since that file is no longer available.  In my situation we have different check for merge and non-merge commit. But if user tries to amend a merge commit, the non-merge commit check not applies, which often cause their commit to be rejected.  I am wondering if you have found a way to deal with that situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[The prepare-commit-msg docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_prepare_commit_msg) say:

> It takes one to three parameters. The first is the name of the file that contains the commit log message. The second is the source of the commit message, and can be: message (if a -m or -F option was given); template (if a -t option was given or the configuration option commit.template is set); merge (if the commit is a merge or a .git/MERGE_MSG file exists); squash (if a .git/SQUASH_MSG file exists); or commit, followed by a commit SHA1 (if a -c, -C or --amend option was given).

So `if test $2 = merge` should do it.

Comment: But I can not use the `pepare-commit-msg` hook to verify the commit message format compliance. `prepare-commit-msg` hook is executed **before** message is presented to user in editor. I have to use `commit-msg` hook to parse the message entered by the user after editor is closed. But you also came with the advice to test the existence of .git/MERGE_MSG file which pointed me to the best solution I was looking for - test that the .git/MERGE_MODE file exists. Thanx